# CSS stops working in Chrome after opening console

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm making an app with node.js and have a few html pages that are styled with one css file. After I click on a link (to a subpage) on the home page and open it in a new tab, everything seems fine. However, after I push ctrl+F12 and open the console, the css styles somehow 'stop working', which means:

1. the elements are not styled, even though there is the link tag with style.css in 'Elements' tab in html
2. In Network tab, I can only see style.css file with status 304 listed there (all other js files are not there, even though JS scripts work)
3. When I return to the home page, the css styles are not visible as well (they were before new tab was open, now it's 304 status in Netwok). After refreshing, styles go back (along with status 200).
4. After I refresh the subpage, everything is fine again, opening console does nothing to styles (Network tab shows all the files, including style.css with status 200). After closing/ opening console again, everything is okay too.
5. If I dont't refresh the subage, the styles "come back" when I change window size (although not immediately, after a second). Otherwise there's just html with working js scripts.

This happens only in Chrome (version 53.0.2785.101), only after opening console for the first time. I have no clue why this might be happening.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this. This issue seems to be Chrome bug, discussed for example here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647151
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648023

I am not sure whether my solution is perfect, but it now it seems to work. I just added one option into express.static in my server.js (I use Express JS):

```
app.use(express.static('public', {maxAge: '5d'}));
```

I guess the max-age property is crucial here - it's specified in Cache-Control http header (you can see this in Dev Tools console in Network tab, after clicking on given file). Found this solution mentioned in the first link. If I see further issues, I will update this answer.
I'm sorry I can't explain this problem in details.

Edit: this solution has one major flaw: when I edit my files, the browser still loads the older versions. Therefore, I turn this max-age property off when I wish to see the changes in files. If anyone has better fix, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache in chrome, then restart chrome and try again. 
(A 304 response header is not an error necessarily. It just means that the browser should load the resource from cache. Basically the browser says "Hey, Can I use the same copy of that CSS file that you gave me last time, or has it changed?" and the Server says "It hasn't changed, go ahead and use the copy you have" AKA 304)

If that doesn't fix the issue, you may look into [ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, unfortunately clearing cache doesn't help. I don't think 304 is the problem; for example after changing window size this status doesn't change but the styles go back. This is so weird I thought it was a bug from newest Chrome version.